# Website of apps with grid view

Tags: html, gridview, web, blogger

I am building an app store in my blogger.
The app store must be in grid view.
How can i add images to each coloumn like in the image below?
[Grid view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkTa9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

constructing tables with desired col spanning and borders might help your need. Here is a sample code.

```
<html>
    <table border = "10" cellspacing = "10" cellpadding = "10">
        <tr border = "10"> 
            <td border = "10"> <img src = "abc.JPG" > <h3> Hi this is text below image</h3> </td> 
            <td > <img src = "abc.JPG" > </td> 
            <td > <img src = "abc.JPG" > </td> 
            <td > <img src = "abc.JPG" > </td> 
            <td > <img src = "abc.JPG" > </td> 
        </tr>

        <tr> 
            <td > <img src = "abc.JPG" > </td> 
            <td > <img src = "abc.JPG" > </td> 
            <td > <img src = "abc.JPG" > </td> 
            <td > <img src = "abc.JPG" > </td> 
            <td > <img src = "abc.JPG" > </td> 
        </tr>

    </table>

</html>
```

Comment: how to add a link to that image that gives the desired app link.